# Connecting to a database and inserting data into a table

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to connect to a database and insert data into the pre-existing table. I'm able to connect to the database it seems but am having trouble getting the data to insert into the table. How do I insert
data into a database in visual studio?

I've already learned how to pass parameters and attempted that, but when I run the program I still receive exceptions. I've attached a screenshot of the error when I try and add a new record. I've looked up multiple different syntaxes for the insert statement, but not sure what I am doing wrong. Below I've included three screenshots one is the form itself, the error I receive, and at the bottom the table structure. 
[Insert Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBNKO.png)

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQBF9.png)

```
private void btnAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValidData())
    {
        if (addProduct)
        {
            product = new Product();
            this.PutProductData(product);

            try
            {
                SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source= (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\MMABooks.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
                SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
                sqlComm = sqlConn.CreateCommand();
                sqlComm.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Products (paramColum) VALUES
                                      (@ProductCode, @Description,
                                       @UnitPrice, @OnHandQuantity)";
                sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@ProductCode", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@UnitPrice", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@OnHandQuantity", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                sqlConn.Open();
                sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlConn.Close();

                // Add code here to call the AddProduct method of the ProductDB class.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmAddModifyProduct addProductForm = new 
    frmAddModifyProduct();
    addProductForm.addProduct = true;
    DialogResult result = addProductForm.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        product = addProductForm.product;
        txtCode.Text = product.Code;
        this.DisplayProduct();
    }
}
```

It should enter a record into the Products table. If I get it down for the insert statement, I'll figure out the retrieve, update, and delete.

[TableStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BphY8.png)

Comment: Your INSERT INTO columns don't match your VALUES clause. INSERT INTO Products (paramColumn) should be INSERT INTO Products(ProductCode, Description, UnitPrice, OnHandQuantity)

Comment: @MaxSzczurek ahh missed that one, yes that also needs to be corrected, you mind if I add that to the answer?

Comment: @peeyushsingh You don't have to ask for permission to make your answer correct.

Comment: I have edited the code in your question according to normal C# conventions. Please remember that readability of your code is important when asking a question here, so take some time to properly format it as I have done. Also, include the error details in your question *as text*, not as an image of the error. Images should be supplementary, but they shouldn't be necessary to get crucial details.

Comment: @peeyushsingh Please do!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the parameter values, something like:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = "Smith";
command.Parameters.Add("@GenderCode", SqlDbType.Char, 1).Value = "M";.
```

Original answer below, but as pointed in comments below, please avoid it, [reasons](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", product.Code);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", product.Description);
```

In the current code you have just setup the parameters but not passed the value.

> EDIT: Based on @MaxSzczurek comments above

Your INSERT INTO columns don't match your VALUES clause.

`INSERT INTO Products (paramColumn)` should be changed to:

```
INSERT INTO Products(ProductCode, Description, UnitPrice, OnHandQuantity)
```

Comment: Please don't advertise using `AddWithValue()`, that's [evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). ;)

Comment: @stickybit thanks, was not at all aware of it! living under a rock!!

Comment: This helped alot! I fixed the parameters and insert statement, but now I'm getting a primary key constraint error :(

Comment: @Triptonix primary keys are used to make sure that rows can be uniquely identified, your product code is the primary key, you must be inserting two rows with the same product code

Comment: your parameter value would be the value entered by the user, or the variable having the user entered value

Comment: I'm positive that I am entering a different product code, but still, receive the primary key constraint issue. Any other possible reasons why this would be?

Comment: debug and check if the values you are sending are correct, without the code thats all I can tell